# Learn C++ after learning C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm developing a library in C# at the moment and recently bought a great book to help me out but the code snippets are in C++.

Does anyone have a link to a site/PDF that'll give me a crash course in C++? (mainly the syntax rather than pros/cons etc) because I'll be developing in C# but things like ->, ::, &, **, are giving me the shivers. Obviously the languages aren't 100% compatible but if I know what the C++ is doing from a 'theoretical' point of view I can make a stab at rewriting it in C#.

I've had a Google to find the answer but all the sites seem to be "Should I use C++ or C#?", which isn't any good to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe provide the context/premises of your library and we can recommend an alternative text as well.

Comment: The languages actually have  very little in common, _apart_ from some basic syntax - so a guide to the syntax is not likely to help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be too simple for you but http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ is a good place for people who have never seen code before to start.

Comment: This has always been a favorite of mine and I recommend it to friends that are starting out in C++ all the time.

Comment: I downloaded the full PDF tutorial, there's some really useful stuff there

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the best way is to look at some of the articles directed at C++ programmers so you can see the differences (I know you asked vice versa, but this will show you the mindset of C++ programmers).  A good one is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx

And then pick up a cheat sheet like the one at

http://www.dreamincode.net/downloads/ref_sheets/cpp_reference_sheet.pdf

Between the article and the cheat sheet you should be well on your way.

Comment: Thanks, I like the cheat sheet

Answer (score 1):

All you want is a quick way to familiarize yourself with C++ language so that you can read the code and re-implement it in C#. The "quick" however depends on how complex the c++ code is. Nevertheless a good book for someone trying to learn C++ for programmers experienced in newer and easier language is "Accelerated C++".

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful: http://www.code2code.net/